# Difference between "mind on your body" and "body on my mind"

Tags: differences

What's the difference between

> Got my mind on your body

and

> Got your body on my mind

This is in the new song *Cool for the Summer* by Demi Lovato.

Comment: This goes to the heart of a philosophical issue. Is the *mind* active or re-active?  *Mind on body* and *body on mind* amount to the same thing, but infer different means by which it got there.

Comment: @WS2 Very interesting! I hadn't seen this distinction. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference.  In "CftS," both mean "I'm thinking about having sex with you."

Comment: Oh, OK. So since she says both sentences one after another, I guess she *really* thinks about having sex with someone :|.